# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'wrapper' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css

am using Inspinia admin theme. i just implement one of the modal effect from below link [enter link description here](http://dixso.github.io/custombox/) modal effect name "slip"

the effect would comes into life when click one of the menu from hover popup which belong from side nav bar.

Issue: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'wrapper' of undefined

am using Angular for front-end and latest bootstrap framework.

by default: angular bootstrap has already .wrapper class.

is that naming conflict or what?

already came across some good solution from stack overflow but i couldn't able to use it effectively.

kindly suggest solution with jsfiddle. it would very greatfull

thanks for the heads up

Comment: Where is the code? Show us something so we can help

Comment: @Endless trying to upload my codes but got some confusion on what part of code from "css and JS" files to be posted

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have encountered is that you try to use the `wrapper` member of an object which is `undefined`. Reproduction example:

```
var foo;
var bar = foo.wrapper;
```

It is advisable to search for

> .wrapper

in your javascript code and find where it is being used and what object is assumed to have such a member, then fix the issue.

Comment: now going to try your suggestion. if its not work me, i ll get back to you. thanks for the heads up

Comment: @beep, you are welcome and I wish you the best of luck.